# Get user's current location when they click on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

I am building a web application based on users current location using javascript/jquery. How to get current location of user when he browse my application on all browsers?

Comment: By location, you mean lat//long or address? What have you done so far?

Comment: Might not be possible in *all* browsers

Answer (score 4):

> ## You can use the geolocation object
>
> Check out [this MSDN Geolocation Article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation), or Mozilla [`navigator.geolocation` Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation)

#### 1. Check browser compatibility

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```

#### 2. Get Current Position

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

#### 3. Watch for Changes

```
var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

### Basic Working Example

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Also, have a look at [this example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/), by MSDN which is slightly more comprehensive.

**Note:** Geolocation only works on [SSL sites with secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)

### Browser Support

You also asked for it to work in **all browsers**. As with most features this isn't really possible. But you can check whether the users browser supports navigator.geolocation, and display an appropriate message if not.

Check out https://caniuse.com/#search=geolocation to see current browser support for geolocation. But in summary, it's supported on:

- IE9+
- Edge 13+
- FF 3.5+
- Safari 5.0+
- Chrome 5.0+
- Opera 11.5, 12.1, 16.6+
- iOS Safari 3.2+
- Android default browser for OS versions 2.1+

*Hope that helps*

Answer (score 1):

you can use geolocation API ..  for more details you can refer this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) API available in all modern browsers. By using this you can get the user's location via the most optimal way for their device, i.e. via GPS or IP.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like below code can help. You can call getLocation() and it will save the location inside _position variable which can be used later.

```
var _position;

function getLocation(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

var onSuccess = function(position) {
    _position = position;
};

function onError(error) {
    alert('Error: ' + error.message);
}
```